# mousemove but only trigger once if in an element

Tags: jquery

How can I improve the following so that I only trigger an event once per element?

http://jsfiddle.net/victorfoster/Q3JmZ/1/

I would like a square to only be toggled once when dragging over it, not multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `mouseenter`.